# Pop up on product page to related articles

Tags: product-page, popup

Cant find a solution to my problem so I'm gonna try ask in here.

My shops have a blog function, where we almost daily post articles. 
Now we want to lead our users to these articles.

And the idea is we want to have a pop up/slid ind/ notice block when you are on a product. that lead to a related article.

I know its complicated, and can have a lot of manuel work. But thats how the big boys want it here.

Do you have eny idea?

Comment: why don't you use product attribute?? Where you will put the id or url of blog post. Then you can fetch those as you want

Comment: Do you need a popup in every product reached to product detail page?

Comment: I need to have controll over with productpage have the pop up to target more presice. 
@AsishHira, good idea, but what if i want a text snippet from the article in the pop up?